# How do i connect to mongodb on openshift

Tags: mongodb, openshift

I have created MongoDB on openshift v3 is it possible to connect to that MongoDB 
using the Robomongo  can you please explain the procedure

Comment: If Robomongo is something you run on your own machine, then use port forwarding. See ``oc port-forward`` command.